# Tumblr site not responsive

Tags: css, tumblr

I'm having difficulty making my Tumblr site responsive. So far I have only managed to make the header responsive. The images load up horizontally instead of vertically on the main page. On all the other pages the header is responsive but the images stay large.

This changed the header -

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

To change the size of the images I added this but it did not work -

```
height:100%;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
```

What am I doing wrong??? In the CSS I have added all the @media screen but it still doesn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you could eloborate a little more with code if would me useful to figure out the solution. 
But hey, lemme give you a sample...

HTML:

```
<div class="ttt">
    <img src="http://www.moovweb.com/content/uploads/2013/09/stackoverflow-logo.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ttt {
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

And here is a working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eV5FQ/)** Try changing the width of the mother div. Same can be applied with @media queries. :)

Comment: I tried adding a class to the content but it didn't work. Here is what it currently looks like on an iPhone - http://static.tumblr.com/qh1bsky/AXRmw5rll/afterlight.jpeg

Comment: Can you provide your media queries?

Comment: Apart from the logo, I don't see any media queries to resize the images? Try giving an explicit width to the image class in the media queries just like you did for logo

Comment: I added  .container img {
    height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height:auto; but to no avail

Comment: Are you saying that you have it in media queries but not showing up? Try something like `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .container img { width: 500px ;  height:auto; } }`

Comment: Yeah, I added it to the media queries but it made no difference when I checked it on an iPhone

Comment: Try `@media only screen and (max-device-width:767px)` instead of `@media only screen and (max-device-width:767px)`  check this link for more on @media queries for ihpone http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone